# MongoDB: Query model and check if document contains object or not, then mark / group result

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a Model called Post, witch contains an property array with user-ids for users that have liked this post.

Now, i need to query the post model, and mark the returned results with likedBySelf true/false for use in by client - is this possible?

I dont have to store the likedBySelf property in the database, just modify the results to have that property.

A temporary solution i found was to do 2 queries, one that finds the posts that is liked by user x, and the ones that have not been liked by user x, and en map (setting likedBySelf true/false) and combine the 2 arrays and return the combined array. But this gives some limitations to other query functions such as limit and skip.

So now my queries looks like this:

```
var notLikedByQuery = Post.find({likedBy: {$ne: req.body.user._id}})
var likedByQuery = Post.find({likedBy: req.body.user._id})
```

(I'm using the Mongoose lib)

PS. A typical post can look like this (JSON):

```
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "55fc463c83b2d2501f563544"
    },
    "__t": "Post",
    "groupId": {
        "$oid": "55fc463c83b2d2501f563545"
    },
    "inactiveAfter": {
        "$date": "2015-09-25T17:13:32.426Z"
    },
    "imageUrl": "https://hootappprodstorage.blob.core.windows.net/devphotos/55fc463b83b2d2501f563543.jpeg",
    "createdBy": {
        "$oid": "55c49e2d40b3b5b80cbe9a03"
    },
    "inactive": false,
    "recentComments": [],
    "likes": 8,
    "likedBy": [
        {
            "$oid": "558b2ce70553f7e807f636c7"
        },
        {
            "$oid": "559e8573ed7c830c0a677c36"
        },
        {
            "$oid": "559e85bced7c830c0a677c43"
        },
        {
            "$oid": "559e854bed7c830c0a677c32"
        },
        {
            "$oid": "559e85abed7c830c0a677c40"
        },
        {
            "$oid": "55911104be2f86e81d0fb573"
        },
        {
            "$oid": "559e858fed7c830c0a677c3b"
        },
        {
            "$oid": "559e8586ed7c830c0a677c3a"
        }
    ],
    "location": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [
            10.01941398718396,
            60.96738099591897
        ]
    },
    "updatedAt": {
        "$date": "2015-09-22T08:45:41.480Z"
    },
    "createdAt": {
        "$date": "2015-09-18T17:13:32.426Z"
    },
    "__v": 8
}
```

Comment: can you provide json for your collection?

Comment: @HarshPatel i've included a JSON example in the question now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that MongoDB's aggregation with $project tequnique was my best bet. So i wrote up an aggregation like this.

Explanation:
Since i want to keep the entire document, but $project purpose is to modify the docs, thus you have to specify the properties you want to keep. A simple way of keeping all the properties is to use "$$ROOT".

So i define a $project, set all my original properties to doc: "$$ROOT", then create a new property "likedBySelf", which is marked true / false if a specified USERID is in the $likedBy set.

I think that this is more clean and simple, than querying every single model after a query to set a likedBySelf flag. It may not be faster, but its cleaner.

```
Model.aggregate([
        { $project: {
            doc: "$$ROOT",
            likedBySelf: {
                $cond: {
                    "if": { "$setIsSubset": [
                        [USERID],
                        "$likedBy"
                    ]},
                    "then": true,
                    "else": false
                }
            }
        }}
    ]);
```

Answer (score 0):

@tskippe you can use a method like following to process whether the post is liked by the user himself and call the function anywhere you want.

```
var processIsLiked = function(postId, userId, doc, next){
  var q = Post.find({post_id: postId});
  q.lean().exec(function(err,res){
    if(err) return utils.handleErr(err, res);
    else {
       if(_.find(doc.post.likedBy,userId)){ //if LikedBy array contains the user
          doc.post.isLiked = true;
        } else {
          doc.post.isLiked = false;
        }
      });
      next(doc);
    }
  });
}
```

Because you are using q.lean() you dont need to actually persist the data. You need to just process it , add isLiked field in the post and send back the response. **note that we are manuplating doc directly. Also you chan tweek it to accept doc containing array of posts and iterating it and attach an isLiked field to each post.

Comment: If my case was that i needed to only mark one single post at at time, this would be useful. But i want do a query to get several docs, and mark them at the same time.

Comment: If that is the case , As I said in my answer You can tweek it a little. Get all the docs u need , I am guessing you will have an array of posts. Then pass this array of postIds as a parameter to the process function, you will get back the same array of posts with an additional field of "isLiked" as true or false. If that is what is needed.          var q = Post.find({post: {$in: postIds});  And then executing the query , you can run a forEach loop on the result and apply the isLiked check on each of the objects

Comment: Yes, that could work as well, but i would like if you could do it all in one query. Check my answer, i've posted an aggregation function that does what i need.